# Smasung Galaxy A51 stuck in bootloop, recognized by adb, not responding to adb commands

Tags: adb, samsung, rooting, rom-flashing, boot-loop

I have a Samsung Galaxy A51 that is stuck in a Boot-loop. Phone was originally water damaged, but worked until my Dad tried to charge it. I replaced the inside part of the phone with the USB port. When I run ADB (I have drivers) my phone shows up under ADB devices. But it does not respond to ANY ADB commands, I can't root, or push files. I also tried ODIN but I get "Odin Protocol version ERROR".
MAIN PROBLEM: phone shows up under ADB devices but does not respond to any ADB commands.
Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: how exactly it shows up in adb, is it authorized? adb kill-server might be required on each reboot loop cycle. try to spam prompt with adb logcat during boot